# CSS doesn't send correctly while adding sub-sites in Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

Please keep in mind that I'm a newbie in Express stuff etc.

I have an issue, that CSS doesn't load for what I call "sub-sites".

By sub-sites, I mean addresses with at least 2 slashes e.g. `domain.com/site/subsite`.

I'm using an Express app:

```js
const express = require(`express`);
const app = express();
const port = 80;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + `/public_html`)); // For serving CSS & JS to websites

app.get(`/`, (req, res) => { // Root domain
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/index.html`)
});

app.get(`/website`, (req, res) => { // Another, example site
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/website1.html`)
});

app.get(`*`, (req, res) => { // For 404
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/404.html`, 404)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`));
```

In this case, CSS & JS work just fine.

**However,** when I do:

```js
app.get(`/website/subsite`, (req, res) => { // A website with 2 slashes in it
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/website2.html`)
});
```

even though no code is changed from the normal, CSS or JS do not send with the website.

I should also mention that all my files are in the `public_html` folder:

```
ProjectDirectory:
  |> server.js
  |> package.json
  |> package-lock.json
  |> public_html/:
    |> index.html
    |> website1.html
    |> website2.html
    |> css/:
      |> index.css // Corresponding css file to index.html
      |> website1.css
      |> website2.css
    |> js/:
      |> ...
```

Every `html` page has a `link` tag:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/*correct file*.css">`

**This also happens when you type /website/ and not just /website**.

The error which pops up while loading the sub-websites:

> Refused to apply style from 'URL' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
>   I seriously tried many solutions, but couldn't find the right one.

*If you do not understand my problem, please explain how to properly include css & js files in ExpressJS.*

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line in your html files: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/*correct file*.css">`. The request for the css file is submitted relativ to the current URL because of **./css/[...]**. Change the line to use absolute paths from the root domain like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/*correct file*.css">` (note the missing dot in front of the first slash).

This also fixes the problem with `/website/`, because the trailing slash was changing the path for the css to `/website/css/website1.css`, which could not be resolved by express.

server.js

```
const express = require(`express`);
const app = express();
const port = 80;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + `/public_html`)); // For serving CSS & JS to websites

app.get(`/`, (req, res) => { // Root domain
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/index.html`)
});

app.get(`/website`, (req, res) => { // Another, example site
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/website1.html`)
});

app.get(`/website/subsite`, (req, res) => { // A website with 2 slashes in it
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/website2.html`)
});

app.get(`*`, (req, res) => { // For 404
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `/public_html/404.html`, 404)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`));
```

exemplary website1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/website1.css">
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution worked wonders and I got exactly what I needed. I was struggling with this problem for so much time so that's why I am posting this comment saying "thank you" (normally I don't do this on any forums...)

Comment: Glad I could help :)